# Why do coordinates have to be inverted to form a dual basis?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, vectors

I am reading Guidry's *Modern General Relativity*, and there is a definition for dual basis vectors that are as follows: 
If we have three coordinates $x(u,v,w)$, $y(u,v,w)$, and $z(u,v,w)$ where we assume these are invertible, we can solve for $u(x,y,z)$, $v(x,y,z)$, and $w(x,y,z)$. From here, we define the basis vectors to be
$e^u\equiv \nabla u = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\hat{i} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\hat{k} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\hat{k}$, and similarly for $e^v$ and $e^w$. My question is why we can't say the normal to the surface is constructed by taking the gradient of the original coordinates $x(u,v,w)$, $y(u,v,w)$, and $z(u,v,w)$, thus making the dual basis vector defined as $e^x\equiv \nabla x = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\hat{i} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\hat{k} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\hat{k}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a typo in your question, but the basis vectors induced by the coordinates $(u,v,w)$ are e.g.
$$\hat e_u = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \hat i + \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \hat j + \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \hat k $$
where the partial derivatives are taken while holding $v$ and $w$ constant.  We define the dual basis $\hat e^u$ by the requirement that for all $i\in\{u,v,w\}$, $\hat e^i \cdot \hat e_j = \delta^i_j$; this  turns out to be
$$\hat e^u = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\hat i + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \hat j + \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} \hat k$$
where $\partial u/\partial x$ is the derivative of $u$ while holding $y$ and $z$ constant.